# Scanner hasNextLine() doesn't access last line in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, treemap

I am using TreeMap structure in Java. The key contains character ':' in it and the values is a list of things. The problem is when i debug the program stops at this line (not working anymore...)

```
if (!string.isEmpty()) {
    **string = jin.nextLine();**
}
```

I really have no idea what can be the problem. Here below is my code. Data(where I keep date variable) and ListOfBills (where I keep list of objects of the Bill Class) are two other Classes.

```
public void read(InputStream in) throws ParseException {
        Scanner jin = new Scanner(in);
        TreeMap<Date, ListOfBills> tree = new TreeMap<Date, ListOfBills>();
        ListOfBills obBill = new ListOfBills();
        Data data;
        String string = jin.nextLine();
        while (jin.hasNextLine()) {
            if (string.contains(":")) {
                data = new Data((string));
                string = jin.nextLine();
                while (!string.contains(":")) {
                    String[] parts1 = string.split(" ");
                    obBill.listOfBills.add(new Bill(Integer.parseInt(parts1[0]), Float.parseFloat(parts1[2]),
                            parts1[3], Float.parseFloat(parts1[5])));                   
                    if (!string.isEmpty()) {
                        string = jin.nextLine();

                    }
                }
                tree.put(data.date1, obBill);

            }

        }
        for (Date date : tree.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(date + "\n");
        }
        jin.close();

    }
```

Comment: You are not testing `jin.hasNextLine()` each time you call `string = jin.nextLine();` so this is bound to be error prone.

Comment: Once `if (string.contains(":"))` is false, you will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps blocked because it is waiting an input ...
You need to enter a value in your stdin if your testing from console ...

Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried that with adding a simple string like 'END', and it is crashing on it, and than I added a new empty line, and goes til the end but crashing at this line: while(jin.hasNextLine()){...}

Comment: can you supply the input you were testing ?